# Explain the behaviour of problem and why use case was rejected?

Tags: java

I had one leetcode challenge, details are below.

**Check If Array Pairs Are Divisible by k**

Given an array of integers arr of even length n and an integer k.

We want to divide the array into exactly n / 2 pairs such that the sum of each pair is divisible by k.

Return True If you can find a way to do that or False otherwise.

```
Example 1:

Input: arr = [1,2,3,4,5,10,6,7,8,9], k = 5
Output: true
Explanation: Pairs are (1,9),(2,8),(3,7),(4,6) and (5,10).
Example 2:

Input: arr = [1,2,3,4,5,6], k = 7
Output: true
Explanation: Pairs are (1,6),(2,5) and(3,4).
Example 3:

Input: arr = [1,2,3,4,5,6], k = 10
Output: false
Explanation: You can try all possible pairs to see that there is no way to divide arr into 3 pairs each with sum divisible by 10.
Example 4:

Input: arr = [-10,10], k = 2
Output: true
Example 5:

Input: arr = [-1,1,-2,2,-3,3,-4,4], k = 3
Output: true
 

Constraints:

arr.length == n
1 <= n <= 10^5
n is even.
-10^9 <= arr[i] <= 10^9
1 <= k <= 10^5
```

Some basic use case above to evaluate the result.

**My Implementation**

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
class Solution {
   public static boolean canArrange (int[]arr, int k)
   {
        if(arr.length % 2 != 0){
            return false;
        }
        int pairs = arr.length / 2;
        int[] firstPair = new int[pairs];
        int[] secondPair = new int[pairs];
            int n =0;
        for(int i=0; i<arr.length;i++){
            if(i < pairs){
                firstPair[i] = arr[i];
            }else{
                secondPair[n] = arr[i];
                n++;
            }
        }
        System.out.println ("pairs =" + pairs);
        int divisablePairs = 0;
        ArrayList<Integer> firstElement = new ArrayList();
        ArrayList<Integer> secondElement = new ArrayList();
        for (int i = 0; i < firstPair.length; i++)
          {
        for (int j = 0; j < secondPair.length; j++)
          {
            
        if ((firstPair[i] + secondPair[j]) % k == 0 && (firstPair[i] + secondPair[j]) >= 0)
          {
            firstElement.add(firstPair[i]);
            secondElement.add(secondPair[j]);
            System.out.println ("(" + firstPair[i] + "," + secondPair[j] + ")");
            divisablePairs++;
          }
      }
      }
    return divisablePairs > 0 ? true : false;
  }
}
```

Here one particular use case is getting failed but I am not sure why. Use case give below.

```
Input:
Array - [9606,4830,4037,-1054,3308,6966,6528,3953,473,-388,9878,-3797,2598,-3283,5813,-6446,-3625,-107,-8756,-3053,-2131,6609,4192,7408,1115,7456,-5674,1219,-8548,540,-9630,-4858,-2453,-726,9902,6192,-7996,1459,-1980,4285,-2659,4156,-2303,-855]
K - 10
My Output:
true
Expected:
false
```

Someone explain what is the issue with my implementation?

Comment: I don't think you can use same element twice

Comment: which one, input element?

Comment: Each element of the array should be used and cannot be used more once . But in your method ,each element can be used more than once. If I input an array like [1,1,8.9], your method will return true, because of (1,9),(1,9),  '9'  is used twice and '8' is never used.

Comment: @learner yes input element cannot be used twice I beleive

Comment: Your algorithm is not 'dividing the array into exactly n/2 pairs'. Rather it is finding n/2 pairs of elements, including duplicates. To solve this problem you actually need to test all combinations of pairs.

Comment: Input: arr = [-10,10], k = 2
Output: true , How does this possible?

Comment: @sprinter updated my implementation, still below case failing
Input:
[3,8,17,2,5,6]
k = 10
Output:
true
Expected:
false

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here we can use an integer map of `k` size.

This'll pass through:

```
public class Solution {
    public static boolean canArrange(int[] arr, int k) {
        int[] countMapRemainders = new int[k];

        for (int a : arr) {
            int remainder = a % k;

            if (remainder < 0) {
                remainder += k;
            }

            countMapRemainders[remainder]++;
        }

        for (int i = 1; i < k; i++) {
            if (countMapRemainders[i] != countMapRemainders[k - i]) {
                return false;
            }
        }

        return countMapRemainders[0] % 2 == 0;
    }
}
```

#### Inputs:

```
[1,2,3,4,5,10,6,7,8,9]
5
[9606,4830,4037,-1054,3308,6966,6528,3953,473,-388,9878,-3797,2598,-3283,5813,-6446,-3625,-107,-8756,-3053,-2131,6609,4192,7408,1115,7456,-5674,1219,-8548,540,-9630,-4858,-2453,-726,9902,6192,-7996,1459,-1980,4285,-2659,4156,-2303,-855]
10
```

#### Outputs:

```
true
false
```

---

### References

- For additional details, you can see the [Discussion Board](https://leetcode.com/problems/check-if-array-pairs-are-divisible-by-k/discuss/). There are plenty of accepted solutions with a variety of [languages](https://support.leetcode.com/hc/en-us/articles/360011833974-What-are-the-environments-for-the-programming-languages-) and explanations, efficient algorithms, as well as asymptotic [time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_complexity)/[space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Space_complexity) complexity analysis<sup>[1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation), [2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Analysis_of_algorithms)</sup> in there.